# not able to see all columns after executing PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am not able to see all the columns of sql server after executing powershell scripting.

Can anyone please explain?

The script I developed is:

```
$dataSource = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$user = "zzzzzzzz"
$pwd = "cccccccc"
$database = "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
$connectionString = "Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=True;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table]"
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query 
$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
$table = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
$table.Load($result)
$table | format-table  $format -Wrap -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 | Out-File C:\test\pratik.txt
$connection.Close()
```

Comment: `$format` is undefined

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the section about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).